# Use of “in” to show form of something

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

Use of “in” to show form of something confuses me. I mean can it be used in every structure while identifying form of something. Would the sentence below be correct ?

> New fish oils will be in pill .

Should i add “form” after pill . If i don’t need to add , aren’t there a few meaning in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to tell someone what form a thing takes, then add the word form after the noun. Just using the word "in" isn't enough. If you mean "fish oils in pill form," then you would need to add "form" after pill. Here's another example. "The toothpaste I use comes **in gel form**." Here's a further example: "The new drug that cures baldness comes ***in powder form***."

It's also possible to say "in the form of a pill" or, "in the form of a gel", or "in the form of a powder." I hope this helps. Do some Internet searches on the word "form" and see other ways it's used.